# How do you set up Xilocore to backup to our own remote location?

Tags: backup

We are currently running Xilocore to do backups locally and to Xilocore's offsite, but since we have multiple offices in different parts of the country, I'm thinking we can drop paying for Xilocore's offsite and start doing our backups between offices. Our Xilocore setup was done by someone before I came to the company and right now, no one really had any idea of how we would accomplish this. If anyone has any experience with setting up Xilocore and doing backups between two remote offices, I'd love to hear how you did it!

Also, I'm totally cool with links to sites explaining this, even if just a start. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xilocore is a cloud BCDR solution.  Your Xilocore appliance is backing up to a primary vault at one of thier data centers then replicated to a secondary vault. It is not designed to replicate between offices.  On the other hand your Xilocore appliance, the client may be installed on your own hardware as well, could backup both your offices and then offsite to the Xilocore vault.

It sound like you may be the end user. If that is the case you should contact the VAR/IT servicce company that installed XiloCore.  I am with a VAR that partners with Xilocore to provide BCDR services to our customers and can help you with any other questions if you do not have a VAR to contact.

Comment: I see. Trying to talk to my VAR is like talking to a brick wall sometimes... was hoping to try and take things over a little. Oh well. Thanks for the info.